# Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":plugins}'

Tags: java, maven, plugins, pom.xml

I got this error when trying to configure a pom xml to start building a project, but I don't how to fix. I tried so hard, deleting and adding characters, but I didn't succeed.
It seems like, the problem is in the "plugins".

Does anyone have a tip?

Thank you in advance!

This is my pom file:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.Dev2021</groupId>
    <artifactId>aula-configurando-o-spring-framework</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>aula-configurando-o-spring-framework</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build/>
        <plugins/>
            <plugin/>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.3</version>
                <configuration/>
                    <source>1.14</source>
                    <target>1.14</target>
                <configuration/>
             <plugin/>
        <plugins/>
    <build/>
</project>
```

Comment: Check all those opening and closing tags with slashes at the end. Example: the opening `<build/>` should be `<build>`, and the closing `<build/>` should be `</build>`. Also, Java 14 is `14` not `1.14`. These types of issues should give you specific and relevant error messages - so there is something else going on, as well.

Comment: Thanks! @andrewjames. I tried that, but still have an error.  
The compiler demands something that I don't know what it is. 
The versions of spring context and maven got "red" meaning that there is something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SO. Just Replace the  section with the below

```xml
     <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.3</version>
                <configuration/>
                    <release>14</release> 
                <configuration/>
             </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

compare it with your previous code in a diff editor and read through andrewjames's comment. You will be able to work what was wrong previously.

Comment: Your solution uses `1.14` as a Java version - which is invalid.

Comment: Thank you @Karthick. Te error persists. 
I tried what you said and now there is a problem of version.
The new error: java: error: release version 5 not supported.

I picked a solution in this site, but is not working yet.
 https://dev.to/techgirl1908/intellij-error-java-release-version-5-not-supported-376

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please try it out and let us know. 
Indeed it was what @andrewjames exactly pointed out.

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for not answering before. 
I added the dependency and everything worked fine. 
Thanks all.